# Formatear un StringValueOf para que salga con 2 decimales

Tags: java, numberformat

tengo el código para hallar la media de varios números ingresados en Jtextfields que me facilitaron ayer. El caso es que lo hace perfecto pero me gustaría que los decimales fueran 2 y no más.
He estado probando de diferentes maneras que he encontrado por el foro pero no he conseguido hacer que funcione.
Dejo el código por si alguien me puede ayudar.
Muchas gracias de antemano

```
public void notaMedia() {
        //Doy formato para que me salgan 2 decimales
       // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        int totalnotaspuestas = 0;
        double notafinald;
        double sumanotas = 0;
        JTextField[] textFields = {txtnota1, txtnota2, txtnota3, txtnota4, txtnota5};
        for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
            String text = (textField.getText());
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                sumanotas += Double.parseDouble(text);
                totalnotaspuestas++;
            }
        }

        notafinald = sumanotas / totalnotaspuestas;
        String notafinal = String.valueOf(notafinald);
        txtNotaMedia.setText(notafinal);
        System.out.println(notafinal);
    }
```

Comment: "He estado probando de diferentes maneras que he encontrado por el foro pero no he conseguido hacer que funcione": 1. de nuevo, [es.so] _no es un foro_, 2. ¿cuáles fueron esas "diferentes maneras"? Además, se formatea lo que se muestra en pantalla, no el número como tal.

Comment: padaleiana perdón por decir que es un foro. 
He probado a poner df.format, , hacer un Math.round, String.format ("%.2f"). Pero no soy capaz. Lo que me gustaría es que en esta línea :  txtNotaMedia.setText(notafinal); se quedara con los dos decimales ya que es lo que guardo en la BBDD.
Un saludo y gracias de nuevo

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Si ya encontraste respuesta a tu pregunta, ponla _como respuesta_, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Además, debes colocar lo que has intentado como edición a tu pregunta. De nuevo: lee [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score 1):

La solución está en estas líneas de código.

```
 txtNotaMedia.setText(String.format( "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(notafinal)));
 System.out.println(String.format( "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(notafinal)));
```

Lo que he hecho es añadir esto: `(String.format( "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(notafinal)));` y ahora me lo muestra con 2 decimales.